# ASP.net LINQ on DataView

Tags: asp.net, dataview

When i have a DataView Operation as

```
 EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query 
    = from order in _table.AsEnumerable()
      where order.Field<Int32>("key") > 2 && order.Field<Int32>("key") < 4
      select order.Field<Int32>("key")=1000, order.Field<string>("name");
```

I can't form the above expression.

When i try

```
select new {key= 1000,name= order.Field<string>("name") };
```

i got

```
    Cannot implicitly convert type 
   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>'   
    to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>'
```

How to form the right query? My task is to replace the key with 1000 and leave the name as is.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `select new {key= 1000,name= order.Field<string>("name") }`, you're creating a new anonymous type that has nothing to do with `DataRow`.
Therefore, you can't assign it to a `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`.

To fix the compiler error, change `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` to `var`.

---

However, that won't fix your underlying problem.
LINQ cannot be used to modify data.

You need to use a normal `foreach` loop and set the `key` values, like this:

```
var affectedRows = from order in _table.AsEnumerable()
  where order.Field<Int32>("key") > 2 && order.Field<Int32>("key") < 4
  select row;
foreach(DataRow row in affectedRows) {
    row["key"] = 1000;
}
```

This code will modify the original `DataRow`s in the original `_table`.
If you don't want to modify the original `_table`, you can copy it by calling `DataTable.Copy()`.

Comment: Since var is of local use i need EnumerableRowCollection

Comment: Later i have to apply some filter operation on DataView

GridView1.DataSource = query.AsDataView();
GridView1.DataSource = _t;

Comment: Then you can write `GridView1.DataSource = affectedRows.AsDataView();`.

Comment: thanks now i am able to perform the task,thank for your code.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.